# Ajax site performance problem (IE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, performance, internet-explorer

I am facing a performance issue related to running ajax in IE (i'm using Ie8), the problem is my website working very slow in ie but it works fine in chrome, and I mean by using SLOW => slow motion . I am using divs and tables and rendering html to div using javascript, besides that I'm using ajax to call 5 different pages (handlers)

```
    function ReceiveServerData(rValue)
    {


        var x = GetHash();
        var feeds = JSON.parse(rValue);
        var sb = new StringBuilderEx();
        var length = feeds.length;
        for(var i=0; i<length-1; i++)
            sb.append(News(feeds[i].Id, feeds[i].Title, feeds[i].Des, feeds[i].Icon, i));
        if(i == 0)
            {
                $('#News').html("");
                $('#head').html("<i><b><center>لا يوجد اي مقالات حاليا</center></b></i>");
                return;
            }

        $('#News').html(sb.toString());
        $('#Pages').html("");
        if(feeds[i].count == 1)
        {
            $('#head').html("");
            return;
        }
        for(var a = 1; a <= feeds[i].count; a++)
        {

        if('#'+a == x || a == x)
            $('#Pages').append("<button id=b" + a + " class='bt2' type='button'><span class='yt-uix-button-content'>"+ a +" &nbsp;</span></button> "); 
            else
                $('#Pages').append("<button id =" + a + " Onclick=javascript:ChangeHash(" + a + ") class='bt' type='button'>"+ a +"</button> "); 
        $('#head').html("<i><b><center>The page has been loaded.</center></b></i>");
    }
        scroll(0,0);
    }
        function News(id, title, des, icon, i)
    {
        var type = "";
        if(i == 0)
            type = "&p=big"; 
        return "<table style=width:100%;>" + 
        "<tr><td rowspan=2 style=width:10%;><img width=70 hieght=70 src="+ icon +">" +
        "</td><td align=right style=width:90%;background:url(./Images/BabrBackground.gif)>" +
        "&nbsp;<font size=3><a href=Read.aspx?id="+ id +">&nbsp; "+ title +"</a></font></td></tr><tr>"+
        "<td valign=top align=right>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i><font color=#5C5858>"+ des +"</font></i></td></tr></table>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

IE's javascript engine tends to run slower than Chrome, and from the looks of it, your loop is probably making it work harder than its suppose to.
Not knowing anything about your project or what you are trying to accomplish, why do you not just render your html on the server and post that back to the client, instead of having all that javascript build the html for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct answer to your question. But you can use dynaTrace to pinpoint exact line of code which is causing the issue. For more information - http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

I would look at optimising the html generation - have you checked out jTemplates?

I currently use jTemplates to create content from ajax returned JSON data which is inserted into divs on the page - I have no issues with performance despite generating a considerable amount of html content - largely I suspect because jTemplates is highly optimised.